# Does the polymerization process include cooling?

Tags: organic-chemistry

The process of seasoning a cast iron pan includes covering the cast iron with a small amount of fat or oil and heating the cast iron to the oil's smoke point.  The oil recombines into polymers and bonds to the cast iron, createing a non-stick surface and protecting the cast iron from rust.
The instructions on my cast iron pans don't mention multiple layers. Other material suggest letting the pan cool between layers, however the instructions for my cast iron crepe makers state to apply ten coats of oil without cooling, but simply waiting for the oil to stop smoking before applyin the next coat.
I'm not a chemist, but I do like to understand what I'm doing and why. This question seems to be beyond the pale of internet research.

My questions are:
Does the cast iron need to cool to complete the polymerization and bonding process?
If I apply a layer of oil and wait for the oil to stop smoking, then apply another layer, have a skipped a step in the  polymerizatio or bonding process (cooling step)?
Will the bond of the seasoned layers be as strong as when the cast iron is allowed to cool between coats?

Thanks to all you who sacrifed time and brain cells to understand chemistry, and thanks to those chemists who are willing to help me understand this.

Comment: I guess that if you cooled, the layers would be more discrete, but is this better, or worse...

Comment: If you want to cure a cast iron pan simply add some cooking oil and saute some onions gently and make a fried onion sandwich. Then wash the pan very gently between uses and repeat if metal shows up. Always dry the inside completely after washing. several cookings will give a good surface. You really do not want a surface of burnt oil. This is my experience as a cook and a chemist